# Добавление элементов в корзину ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть 2 отдельных массива

```
export const crepes = [
    { "id": "1", image: baconCrepe, title: "Bacon", 
    description: 'Mozzarella, grilled chicken, fried bacon, fresh tomatoes, BBQ sauce, spinach, arugula', price: '5$'},
    { "id": "2", image: fourCheeseCrepe, title: "4 cheese", 
    description: 'Mozzarella, gorgonzola, camembert, parmesan, white sauce, arugula', price: '5$'},
    { "id": "3", image: nutellaCrepe, title: "Nutella", 
    description: 'Nutella, Oreo bisquits, strawberries', price: '5$'},
    { "id": "4", image: salmonCrepe, title: "Salmon", 
    description: 'Philadelphia cheese, fresh salmon, avocado, fresh cucumber', price: '5$'},
    { "id": "5", image: vegeSalad, title: "Vege salad", 
    description: 'Beetroot marinated in honey, Halloumi cheese, pomegranate seeds, lamb`s lettuce, cashew nuts', price: '5$'},
    { "id": "6", image: coleslowSalad, title: "Coleslow salad", 
    description: 'Cabbage, lime juice, mayonnaise, lemongrass, coriander', price: '5$'}
]

export const burgers = [
    { "id": "1", image: cranberryBurger, title: "Cranberry", 
    description: '100% Beef, Camembert, cranberry sauce, red onion, arugula, lamb`s lettuce', 
    price: '5$'},
    { "id": "2", image: italianTaste, title: "Italian taste", 
    description: '100% Beef, mascarpone, black olives, dried tomatoes, red onion, arugula, iceberg lettuce', price: '4$'},
    { "id": "3", image: mushroomBurger, title: "Mushroom", 
    description: '100% beef, mushrooms in sour cream, red onion, arugula, cheddar, iceberg lettuce', price: '4$'},
    { "id": "4", image: seasonalBurger, title: "Seasonal", 
    description: '100% beef, tomato sauce, asparagus, red onion, iceberg lettuce, lamb`s lettuce', price: '5$'},
    { "id": "5", image: vegeBurger, title: "Vege", 
    description: 'Halloumi cheese, red onion, beetroot marinated in honey, homemade sauce, sunflower sprouts, lamb`s lettuce', price: '5$'},
]
```

Они выводятся в компоненте `Menu`

```
<TabPanel>
        <div className="burgers">
          <ul> 
          {burgers.map(burger => (
            <li key={burger.id}>
            <h4>{burger.title}</h4>
            <span>{burger.price}</span>
            <img src={burger.image} alt={burger.title} />
            <p>{burger.description}</p>
            <button type="submit" onClick={() => addToCart()}>Add to cart</button>
            </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
    </TabPanel>
    <TabPanel>
      <div className="crepes">
          <ul>
          {crepes.map(crepe => (
            <li key={crepe.id}>
              <h4>{crepe.title}</h4>
              <span>{crepe.price}</span>
              <img src={crepe.image} alt={crepe.title} />
              <p>{crepe.description}</p>
              <button type="submit" onClick={() => addToCart()}>Add to cart</button>
            </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
  </TabPanel>
```

Я хочу добавить функцию добавления элемента в корзину путем нажатия кнопки `Add to cart`

Что-то вроде этого?

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  const addToCart = () => setCart((currentCart) => [...currentCart]);

<button type="submit" onClick={() => addToCart()}>Add to cart</button>
```

Можно ли как-то соединить эти два массива, чтобы добавлять и бургеры и блины в корзину одной функцией? Как этого достичь? Все примеры, которые я просматривала, были простыми и элементы состояли в одном массиве( ими было легко управлять). Я усложнила себе задачу и запуталась. Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

```
state = {
        cart: []
    }

addToCart = add => {
        const {cart} = this.state;

        if (!cart.some(alreadyAdded => alreadyAdded.title === add.title)) {
            this.setState({
                cart: [...this.state.cart, add]
            });
        }
    };
```

Для хуков соответственно тоже самое, просто без ключевых слов state и setState

Comment: не совсем понятно

Comment: @Ati я взял эту функцию из другой темы, там как раз показан пример для хуков https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63384880/how-to-add-a-favorite-item-to-a-newly-created-list